Integrating $\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\sqrt[4]{2x^{2}-1}}$
I came across an integral on some JEE material that captured my interest.$$\text{I}=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\sqrt[4]{2x^{2}-1}}$$ After several failed attempts, I have come here. Can't seem to find a solution for the same. I have absolutely zero idea on how to even begin. Trigonometric substitution seems intimidating ($\cos{2x}$ formula) but I can't seem to progress after some development.
My work: 
$x=\cos\theta \implies dx=-\sin\theta$
$$\text{I}=\int_{ }^{ }-\frac{\sin\theta d\theta}{\sin^{2}\theta\sqrt[4]{\cos2\theta}}=-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\csc\theta d\theta}{\sqrt[4]{\cos2\theta}}$$ and that's pretty much it.I have a fundamental understanding of integral calculus, including techniques like substitution, integration by parts, and basic definite and indefinite integrals.

the integral is not solvable in terms of elementary functions...there must be something else given in the question or else the question is wrong

Please see, S219 of this AoPS post. I found it by using Approach zero search engine.

See $t=\sqrt[4]{2x^2-1}$
$$\int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)\sqrt[4]{2x^2-1}}
= \frac12\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+t^4}{2t^2}}+ \frac12\coth^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+t^4}{2t^2}}
$$
